# Convergence of sequence of compact sets in Hausdorff metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a sequence of compact sets *$K_{i}$* in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ and a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, which satisfy the following 2 conditions.

1. $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $K$, $\exists$ $x_{i}$ $\in$ *$K_{i}$* such that *$x_{i}$* $\rightarrow$ $x$.
2. $\forall$ convergent sequence $x_{i_{j}}$ $\in$ *$K_{i_{j}}$*, $\lim_{j\to\infty}x_{i_{j}}$$\in$ K.

Then show that *$K_{i}$* $\to$ $K$ in Hausdorff metric.

I've already shown that $\forall$ $\epsilon$>0, $\exists$ N$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall$ $i$ $\geq$ N, $\sup_{x\in K } d(x,K_{i}) \leq \epsilon$ by simply using condition 1.

But I got stuck in proving $\sup_{x\in K_{i}} d(x,K) \leq \epsilon$, I really don't know how to use condition 2 to prove this, I tried proof by contradiction, but then I got a subsequence which doesn't converge to $K$, since I don't know that subsequence converges or not, I couldn't get a contradiction, so I guess my problem is I don't know to construct a convergent sequence $x_{i_{j}}$ $\in$ *$K_{i_{j}}$*, but the limit of this sequence does not lie in $K$.

Thanks a lot for all your solutions or suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

The statement you are trying to prove is false. Counterexample in one dimension: $K=\{0\}$, $K_i=\{0,i\}$. Both (1) and (2) hold, but the Hausdorff distance $d(K,K_i)$ tends to infinity.

The problem can be saved by adding the assumption that $\bigcup K_i$ is bounded. Then your proof can be finished as follows:

Suppose $\sup_{x\in K_{i}} d(x,K)\not\to0$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_{i_j}\in K_{i_j}$ such that $d(x_{i_j},K)\ge \epsilon$. Since $x_{i_j}$ is bounded, it has a convergent subsequence. This latter subsequence contradicts (2).

Comment: thanks, that was very helpful:)